# Form submit supposed to refresh only Div, but instead refreshes Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

I have a PHP page included called 'leaguestatus.php'. This page allows the user to post a message/status update and the intent is to have only this part of the div refreshed; however, on submit, the entire page is reloaded.

In the current implementation I'm simply printing all the `$_POST` variables to the div so I can see what's coming through. The `MsgText` textarea DOES get posted, however, it's only after the whole page loads. I'm trying to get just the div and that included file to reload.

```
div id="statusupdates"><? include 'leaguestatus.php'; ?></div>
```

**leaguestatus.php**

```
<form id="statusform" method="POST">
<textarea name=MsgText rows=5 cols=40></textarea><BR>
<input type=submit value=Post id=uhsbutton>
</form>

<BR>
<BR>

<div id='formbox'>
<? print "<pre>POST Variables:<BR>";
    print_r ($_POST);
    print "</pre>";
    $MsgText = $_POST["MsgText"];
?>
</div>
```

The jQuery I'm running in the header is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#statusform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData=$(this).serialize();
        var pUrl="leaguestatus.php";

        submitFormSave(formData, pUrl);
    });

    function submitFormSave(formData, pUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: pUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data:formData,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#formbox").html(response);
            }
        }).success(function(){

        });
    }
});
```

Here are my includes:

**html header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Edit: updated code to reflect use of @sazedul's response. Only issue now is on first click page acts as expected (no page refresh). On second click the entire page reloads. On third click we're back to normal.

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors ?

Comment: hmmm... ajaxSubmit is apparently an undefined type... let me dig.

Comment: now I seem to be getting a TypeError for return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this following code for ajax submit hope it will work.

```
$("#statusform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData=$(this).serialize();
var pUrl="leaguestatus.php";

 submitFormSave(formData, pUrl);

    });

     function submitFormSave(formData, pUrl)
     {

        $.ajax({
            url: pUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data:formData,
            success: function(response)
            {

                $("#formbox").html(response);

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: We're almost there... I'm getting no errors, however, I am seeing some odd behaviour: on the first click, the page refreshes no problem and I see the POST data (HURRAH!!)... on the SECOND click, the entire page reloads. If I click a third time, the page refreshes like the first time... no problems.

Comment: I've created a control script where I have nothing else running except for the above code...  the second-click behaviour is not happening...  something else is going on with my other scripts that is causing the issue. MANY MANY thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Made the following changes in your leaguestatus.php 
 remembar to put double quote in the name="MsgText" in text area.

```
<form id="statusform" method="POST">
<textarea name="MsgText" rows=5 cols=40></textarea><BR>
<input type=submit value=Post id=uhsbutton>
</form>

<BR>
<BR>

<div id='formbox'>

</div>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['MsgText'])){

$message=$_POST['MsgText'];

echo $message;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like the code below....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#statusform").submit(function() {
        $("div").load();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to preventDefault of submit then other thing

so,you have to use e.preventDefault() to prevent submit.then do what ever you want

```
 $("#statusform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

......

Comment: This has given me more success (ie. no posting), however, I'm still getting this TypeError: undefined is not a function for the $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); line. I've made sure the jquery.form.js line is added, but honestly, not sure what else I need for this to be working.

Comment: Complete error is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function / (anonymous function) / jQuery.event.dispatch / elemData.handle.eventHandle.  I feel I'm close here... this could be the last bit before it works.

Comment: I've also tried changing that $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); to be $.ajax(options); however it doesn't appear to be submitting (or at least there are no POST variables being shown after hitting submit). I'm also getting no errors (so it's slightly encouraging... just need to figure out where those POST variables are going).